# image behind adsense

Tags: css, images

i want to have an image behind my google adsense
just like the below image
[image]

but when i tried the following css

```
L{
    background: transparent url("http://www.triphp.com/images/adback.png") repeat-x left bottom; padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px;
    height: 352px;
    padding: 50px 30px 0;
    width: 350px;
    }
```

i am getting image but as background check this image for this
[image]

how can i make it like the above one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look it's not an image that's behind the ad it's a background colour. Controlled from your adsense setup.

if you go into your ads and edit it. You'll see options to edit "style".  You can then choose the background colour you desire :)

Hope the above makes sense :)

Comment: but in forums i read that it is not possible to make the background of adsense to transparent, we can select the background color to the color of our website
is this true?

Comment: If you look at your screen shot the lines don't carry on through the ad. It's a solid colour.

Comment: yaa that i know, that i am having white color as background, but there is no option for making background as transparent, you can change color of background but not transparent

Answer (score 1):

It's not an image it's a background and for this you need to add css background property to your code. You can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp . You should use

```
.element_id{background-image:url("your_image.gif");}
```