# background css help

Tags: css, google-adsense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [image behind adsense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6791/image-behind-adsense)

i have a google ad, where i want to place an image, i tired the css, but the image is not coming properly,
my google ad size is height=280, width=336
the image url is http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/p/V/F/o/0/notepad-hi.png

i want this image behind my ad, i tried this following code:-

```
{
    background:url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/p/V/F/o/0/notepad-hi.png")transparent;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px 30px 0;
    width: 350px;    
}
```

Comment: You already asked this question and got answers for it (one of which you selected as correct). Don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: but i am not clear with that, and question is related not same,
in this i am asking for code help, there i asked how can i put background image to adsense, here i am asking the code of putting background image to adsense

Comment: It's the same exact question. If you didn't get the information you needed, then you should have kept it open and expanded on the question.

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate question, it is off topic as design questions belong on Doctype. If you have more then 3,000 points you should vote to close the question if you believe it violates is a duplicate question. Remember, this is a community moderated website.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `<div>`
2. Apply your style to the div
3. insert your add into the div

But, the AdSense ads are not transparent, and :

[AdSense Terms and Conditions](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)

> ***Implementation and Operation of Ads, Search Results, and Referrals*** [...] including without limitation by not modifying the JavaScript or other programming provided to You by Google in any way, unless expressly authorized in writing by Google [...]

So, I don't know if a "T.O.S. compliant" technique exist for this...

Comment: that i did, i have a div tage, inside which my ad is placed, but what i want is a background image, my ads background is white, and i have an image whoes background is also white,
i just want it to be placed in background just like this image

http://i.imgur.com/Lr8oX.jpg

i dont the right css for this, how can o do this??